# Extend a homeomorphism of an arc of a circle to the entire circle.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be homeomorphic to a circle.

Let $C_X$ and $C_Y$ be closed arcs of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and there is a homeomorphism $\phi:C_X\to C_Y$.

Is it always possible to extend $\phi$ to $\phi':X\to Y$, such that $\phi'$ is a homeomorphism and $\phi'(x)=\phi(x)$ for $x\in C_X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Wlog. $X=Y=S^1$ (via given homeomorphisms), $C_X=[0,\alpha]$, $C_Y=[0,\beta]$ (per rotation and/or reflection) and the extension $[\alpha,2\pi]\to[\beta,2\pi]$ is straightforward.

Alright, the only trap in this is that we need to show that $\phi$ takes endpoints to endpoints. But that is clear as endpoints can be characterized by the fact that removing thenm does not make the arc disconnected.